# Scalaz: Map of ValidationNel to ValidationNel of Map

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

How do I convert a

```
val source: Map[MyKeyType, ValidationNel[MyErrorType, MyValueType]]
```

to

```
val target: ValidationNel[MyErrorType, Map[MyKeyType, MyValueType]]
```

while capturing all validation errors?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sequence` to turn a type `F[G[A]]` inside out (i.e., into a `G[F[A]]`) if you have two things: an `Applicative` instance for `G` and a `Traverse` instance for `F`. In this case Scalaz provides both off the shelf, so you can just write `source.sequenceU` (where the `U` part indicates that this is a method that uses the `Unapply` trick to help out Scala's type inference system).

For example:

```
scala> println(Map("a" -> 1.successNel, "b" -> 2.successNel).sequenceU)
Success(Map(a -> 1, b -> 2))

scala> println(Map("a" -> 1.successNel, "b" -> "BAD".failureNel).sequenceU)
Failure(NonEmptyList(BAD))
```

And errors will be accumulated as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You want `sequenceU`:

```
val target = source.sequenceU
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. :)

Oddly enough, IntelliJ flags it as an error, but it compiles in sbt.